# IE7 - % width on floated div not applied

Tags: css

The width of the float div when applied % work fine in ie 8,9,10 but not in 7.
here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NHuH8/6
the comment and close need to be @ either ends.what need to be done

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an absolute position for the  `comment` and `close` divs

CSS:

```
#child1{
    background-color:blue;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#child3{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;

}
#comment{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#close{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHuH8/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Give the "parent" CSS declaration a width in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your widths and set the 'close' to `float: right;`. And put 'close' before 'comment', or 'close' will end up on the next line.